# Yahoo format of searched images?

Tags: image, url, yahoo

I know the format for google its `http://www.google.com/search?q=<SEARCH TERM>&tbm=isch`

Anyone know what's the format for yahoo images?
(`https://images.search.yahoo.com/`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
https://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images?p=SEARCHTERM
```

You can easily find this URL. Just make a search on https://images.search.yahoo.com/ and look at the URL. It will likely contain additional unneeded parameters. Remove one, test again, and if it still works, remove another one, etc.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot !